# Modifying compiler options when building RPMS that use cmake

Tags: rhel, rpm, cmake, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm building a package on Rocky 8 that works fine on Fedora 35. When I tried to compile it on Rocky 8 using rpmbuild -ba, I got the error: relocation xxxxx can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC.

Normally this is easy to add, but the spec file uses the macro %cmake to build the project. This macro gets expanded to have a bunch of stuff. In that stuff CFLAGS is defined, among other things. How do I add my -fPIC flag to that stuff? The macro can be obtained using "rpm -E %cmake" but it's not obvious how to add additional flags that are not -D defines.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I could pass -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=ON as a parameter to the %cmake macro.